# Verbal forms allowed to determine a noun

Tags: grammar, conjugations, syntax

I'm not confident that the English grammatical words I'm using are okay; feel free to correct me.

Let's start with the phrase 読{よ}む本{ほん} meaning, among other acceptable translations *"the book I do read"*. The auxiliary *do* I used to translate is nothing but a convenient way to mark the tense (present) and the aspect (not progressive).

That's what I call "a noun determined by a verb" structure since 本{ほん} is determined by 読{よ}む.

My question deals with the other forms of 読{よ}む which may be used to determine 本{ほん}:

- 読{よ}む本{ほん}  : the book I do read
- 読{よ}まない本{ほん} : the book I don't read
- 読{よ}んで本{ほん} : the book I'm reading
- 読{よ}まないで本{ほん} : the book I'm not reading
- 読{よ}んだ本{ほん} : the book I did read
- 読{よ}まなかった本{ほん} : the book I didn't read
- ... ?

**My questions :**

1. Are the above forms grammatically correct?
2. Leaving aside passive and causative, did I forget some forms? I'm particularly curious to know if imperative/volitional forms may have some sense here.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You might want to [look](https://archive.org/stream/historicalgramma00sansuoft#page/132/mode/2up) [up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_grammar#.E9.80.A3.E4.BD.93.E5.BD.A2) the term `連体形` ("attributive" form).

Comment: And thinking about it again, 連用形+名詞 compounds are possible too, eg. 着物 (a thing one wears; wearing-thing), 買い物 (a thing one buys; buying-thing), 読み方 (a way in which one reads; reading-way) etc. Not sure if you would count this, but it's worth mentioning. Also, this is somewhat unrelated, but constructions of the form 〜しての名詞 are possible too, eg. 後は読んでのお楽しみ or それは、読んでの通りよ.

Comment: Thank you again, these details are very interesting. May I ask you what do mean "後は読んでのお楽しみ " and "読んでの通りよ" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it sounds strange to me to put "I" as default subject of the determining sentence. I'd rather explicitly mark a subject, unless it's very clear from its context.
Anyway,

- わたしが読む本 : the book I do read  (O)
- わたしが読まない本 : the book I don't read (O)
- わたしが読んで本 : the book I'm reading (X)
- わたしが読まないで本 : the book I'm not reading   (X)
- わたしが読んだ本 : the book I did read  (O)
- わたしが読まなかった本 : the book I didn't read (O)

To express progressive aspect, we need an auxiliary verb いる.
And, when combining two verbs (読む + いる), we use て,
thus it will be 読む + て + いる = 読んでいる.
So 'the book I'm reading' is わたしが読んでいる本.
Note that 読んでいる is in a perfectly legit ru-verb form(一段動詞). You can then transform it into whatever you want.

```
negative    読んでいる + ない = 読んでいない  (book that) I'm not reading.
past        読んでいる + た = 読んでいた  I was reading.
neg + past  読んでいる + ない + た = 読んでいなかった  I was not reading.
...
```

One more thing one should keep in mind when using progressive is that, in modern Japanese, it's very common to drop い from aux (い)る. So it's fine to say わたしが(読んでる/読んでない/読んでた/読んでなかった)本.

Imperative/volitional forms in general do not modify following nouns.

Comment: Thank you very much : your answer is very clear and informative.